# HttpContext.User as ClaimsPrincipal have all the claims for the user from database

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity, asp.net-core-6.0

We need to set and get the claims condition based. We are trying to set the claims that will be used further.

```
if (activeUser != null)
{
    activeUser.ActivePermissions.ForEach(x => claims.Add(new Claim("Permission", x)));
}

foreach (var role in userRoles)
{
    // var claimsForRoles = await SolutiosRoleManager.GetClaims(role?.Id ?? String.Empty);
    // foreach (var claim in claimsForRoles)
    // {
    //     claims.Add(new Claim(claim.Type, claim.Value));
    // }
                                   
    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role?.Name ?? String.Empty));
}

var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
                                {
                                    IsPersistent = false,
                                };

await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                              new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
                              authProperties);
```

But whenever we are trying to fetch the claims back using

```
var user = HttpContext.User as ClaimsPrincipal;
```

I get all the claims stored in the database for the user. So we basically wants to know whether it is communicating with the database to get all the claims. or there is something in other classes that is setting it up behind the scene.

Thanks

Comment: `HttpContext.User` is used for `Gets or sets the user for this request.` we can see the definition of it. so I don't think it's communicating with the database to get the claims

Comment: Never mind, `await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(loginViewModel.UserName, loginViewModel.Password,loginViewModel.RememberMe, false);`   was the culprit